# Cracking $f(x) = Cx \oplus Dx$

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

A program I reverse engineered is using $f(x) = Cx \oplus Dx$ where `C = 0x20ef138e415` and `D = 0xd3eafc3af14600` as a hash function. Given a byte array, the hash is is obtained by repeatedly applying $f$ to the current hash xor next byte.

Java code:

```
    public static long f(long x) {
        return (0x20ef138e415L * x) ^ (0xd3eafc3af14600L * x);
    }

    public static long hash(byte[] bytes) {
        long hash = 0;

        for (byte b : bytes) {
            hash = f(hash ^ ((b & 0xff) + 1));
        }

        return f(hash);
    }
```

Is there an easy way to generate hash collisions?

Comment: No need to do cryptanalsis, this has a 64 bit state and therefor finding collisions is trivial with ~ 2^32 operations. Thinking is hard finding collisions in this is easy.

Comment: I actually tried doing this for fun, and failed, but my failure lead to this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/92280/many-near-collisions-but-no-full-collision  (My comments still stands it shouldn't be hard to find collisions in any 64 bit hash, I simply have failed none the less).